# how to deploy postgresql database to heroku

Tags: database, heroku

I have database with all the data filled in,How to deploy it to heroku . I am not able to find the solution.   I don't have any knowledge of how to deploy postgres database to heroku .Can anyone explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Based on (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export):

Dump your local database in compressed format using the open source pg_dump tool:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

In order for PG Backups to access and import your dump file you will need to upload it somewhere with an HTTP-accessible URL. We recommend using Amazon S3 with a signed url.

Note that the pg:backups restore command drops any tables and other database objects before recreating them.

Generate a signed URL using the aws console:

```
aws s3 presign s3://your-bucket-address/your-object
```

Use the raw file URL in the pg:backups restore command:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore '<SIGNED URL>' DATABASE_URL
```

`DATABASE_URL` represents the `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL` of the database you wish to restore to. You must specify a database configuration variable to restore the database.

If you’re using a Unix-like operating system be sure to use single quotes around the temporary S3 URL, because it might contain ampersands and other characters that will confuse your shell. If you’re running Windows, you must use double-quotes.

When you have completed the import process, delete the dump file from its storage location if it’s no longer needed.

Comment: heroku pg:backups:restore <'s3://databasesherif001/ONLINEDB.backup'> postgres://gtlxfntrymtooe:4553ab0524af636a90727a6e55d459b2eb0c8ebcf31448315ae508c6c9cad555@ec2-174-129-226-234.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dib9suoli9114  NO such file or directory error is shown

Comment: $ heroku pg:backups:restore 's3://databasesherif001/ONLINEDB.backup' postgres://gtlxfntrymtooe:4553ab0524af636a90727a6e55d459b2eb0c8ebcf31448315ae508c6c9cad555@ec2-174-129-226-234.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dib9suoli9114 --app notedatabaseserver9167
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.26.2 to 7.35.1.
 !    Unknown database:
 !    postgres://gtlxfntrymtooe:4553ab0524af636a90727a6e55d459b2eb0c8ebcf31448315ae508c6c9cad555@ec2-174-129-226-234.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dib9suoli9114.
 !    Valid options are: DATABASE_URL

Comment: $ heroku pg:backups:info r011 --app notedatabaseserver9167
output stream: Expected HTTP Status 200, received: "403 Forbidden"
2019-12-26 13:18:10 +0000 waiting for restore to complete
2019-12-26 13:18:10 +0000 pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file
2019-12-26 13:18:10 +0000 pg_restore finished with errors
2019-12-26 13:18:10 +0000 waiting for download to complete
2019-12-26 13:18:10 +0000 download finished with errors
2019-12-26 13:18:10 +0000 please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible

Comment: heroku pg:backups:restore "https://pojo-database.s3.amazonaws.com/picture.dump"postgres://uuoksxmgxcqskw:45e2ebc90ac4c5712ef867f6139969d4f73252f4b27961a94510e3562600
9e35@ec2-54-235-250-38.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d2gmcra2tqtdh6 --app notedatabaseserver9167